# Can we enable PHP libraries using ini_set(); function?

Tags: php, htmltidy

I have a server that does not support server configuration. I am unable to edit php.ini file in anyway.
I need to enable the libtidy (the HTML tidy library).
I was wondering if there is any way that we can use  ini_set(); function in my php script for enabling libraries.
Or if any external libtidy.php library file is poosible, that i can include and use.
Even if i get libtidy.dll file, can i use its function in PHP by hosting it on the server ?
Thanks.

Comment: No, unfortunately that is not possible. Are you using shared hosting? If so, can you move to a VPS? That is nearly the same price as shared hosting these days, and is much more flexible. Are you using Windows or Linux for your remote host?

Comment: Hmm, you [could try this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php) but if you are on shared hosting, it will be (and afaik should be) disabled.

Comment: I am using a linux based shared hosting unfortunately. The dl() function is even disabled.

Comment: See my earlier comment, then, for your only reasonable alternative. Admittedly, Tidy is available as a PHP4 library in PEAR, but I would urge you to avoid it. Whilst you could perhaps look for another library, I'd recommend moving to a VPS anyway.

Comment: Yeah moving to a VPS seems the only better way. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can enable extensions dynamically using the function [`dl()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php) :

```
dl('extension_name');
```

However, there are some restrictions named in the [manual page of the function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php). Also the extension has to be installed before in order to load it using `dl()`. And it is likely that the function has been disabled in `php.ini` by your hoster. That's why the function might not being very useful for you in shared hosted environment but there is no way beside from using `dl()`.

Comment: Thanks. I am using shared hosting unfortunately. The dl() function is even disabled. Though thanks for the info. I learned a new dl() function.

Comment: You are welcome.. If you really need that library there would be hakish solution I could imagine. But  as others stated it would be better to replace that library from your code.